# Problem with netflix-desktop and xattr

Tags: fstab, netflix

I'm having problems getting `netflix-desktop` to work on Ubuntu 13.04. At first when I tried to run it from terminal I got a message saying something along the lines of `no module xattr`. After installing `xattr`, I now get the message:

```
It appears that you do not have extended file system attributes enabled.
Please enable the user_xattr option for your filesystem and try again.
```

I've found a few threads discussing this problem ([here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2084592), for example), most of which seem to agree to modify `/etc/fstab/` to include `user_xattr`. I've done this, but still get the same message.

Any ideas on what to do?

**Edit:**

This is the output when I do `sudo mount`

```
/dev/sdb2 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/usrname/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=my_usrname)
```

and, incase it's useful, the contents of `/etc/fstab/`:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=263e92a2-9998-4386-8d3b-3d6ea3c8c399 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro, user_xattr 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=e34a5af0-13f0-40c4-987e-34ba143faba5 none            swap    sw              0       0

~
```

Comment: Did you reboot after changing fstab?

Comment: Yeah, i first tried doing `sudo mount -o remount /` as  suggested in the post i linked to above, then i tried just rebooting my entire machine, neither yielded any results. Before I modified fstab i made a duplicate, /etc/fstab1/. I was speculating that this might have been what was causing problems so deleted it, but  i still get the same error when I start netflix-desktop. I notice there is also a directory in /etc/ called fstab.d but it's completely empty...

Comment: Are all the relevant files on the root filesystem? And, please run `sudo mount` (no arguments) and check if `user_xattr` is shown as active. Append the output to your question.

Comment: I just posted the appended the output to the post, as well as the contents of /etc/fstab incase that's useful ... i notice that when i do `sudo mount` the first line of the output says `/dev/sdb2` whereas the 8th line of /etc/fstab mentions `/dev/sda2`. Could this be the problem? I'm a complete noob to all this but i know that /dev/sda is my 1TB HDD and /dev/sdb is my 250GB SSD. When i got the computer the OS was installed on the SSD, but a while back i had to reinstall it. I'm wondering if somehow I re-installed it on the HDD accidentally? Again, I don't really know my way around linux ...

Comment: @nlk22 I know it's a couple of months later, but did you ever get this problem resolved? Having the same issue.

Comment: @bcmcfc Sorry i never responded to that, haven't checked this account in a while. I did get the issue resolve ... although I can't remember exactly how ... If you're still having this issue pm me and maybe we can work through it together.

Answer (score 0):

The fstab fields are whitespace-delimited. You need to get rid of the space before `user_xattr`.

Then run

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

and reboot.

Then see if it shows up in mount.

Comment: So now `user_xattr` shows up when i run `sudo mount`, but I still get the same error when I try to run netflix >.<

Comment: I'm out of ideas. Ask the Netflix client author?